# How do I add "Firmware Setup" option to grub

Tags: grub2

I'm looking for a way to add a menu option to grub that will result in the same screen as the command `systemctl reboot --firmware-setup`. I believe that I can use Grub Costumizer in order to add a script code that will do the work. If that's the case, what's the script?

Comment: linux is not active when grub runs .... grub does have some built in commands that may do the job

Comment: Yes of course, commands that synthesize a script code in order for it to work. That's what I'm asking.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Short answer*: It turns out, the script is dead simple. Simply `fwsetup`.

*Details*:

The fastest way is through Grub Customizer. But it can be done using terminal.

1. Download Grub Customizer

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:danielrichter2007/grub-customizer
sudo apt update
sudo apt install grub-customizer
```

2. Open it and tap the <kbd>+</kbd> icon located in the toolbar
3. Type the name you want (ex. System Setup)
4. Select Type "Other" and type `fwsetup` in the boot sequence
5. Hit OK
6. Click Save at the top left corner to save the configuration.

*The command itself is used to open the firmware setup that differs from one computer to another.*

Comment: Thanks for taking the time to post your solution! Could you please expand it a little though? What did that command do? How did you run it?

Comment: Take a look now. If you need even more details let me know.

Comment: That's great, thanks!